# Python indexing with simplicity

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array `a`,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[3, 2, 2], [3, 4, 2]],
[[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 2]],
[[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 2]]
])
print(a)
```

```
[[[3 2 2]
  [3 4 2]]

 [[1 2 2]
  [3 4 2]]

 [[1 2 2]
  [3 4 2]]]
```

and I want to slice part of it, right now with this way:

```
b = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    if (a[i, 0, 0] > 2 and a[i, 1, 0] > 2):
        b.append(a[i])
print(np.array(b))
```

```
[[[3 2 2]
  [3 4 2]]]
```

I tried method 1

```
a[np.where(a[:,:,0] > 2)]
```

and method 2

```
a[a[:,:,0]> 2]
```

They both result in:

```
array([[3, 2, 2],
       [3, 4, 2],
       [3, 4, 2],
       [3, 4, 2]])
```

Is there any way to deal with the index like method 1 or 2?

Comment: Can you please give your desire output?

Comment: `[[[3 2 2]
  [3 4 2]]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.all(..., axis=1)`:

```
a[np.all(a[:, :, 0] > 2, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the simplicity I want.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a list comprehension which allow you to fit your custom conditions.

```
b = [i for i in a if i[0,0]>2 and i[1,0]>2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is great, but I prefer this way:`a[np.all(a[:, :, 0] > 2, axis=1)]`